# Kotlin RecyclerView in RecyclerView after update a view is going to child RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `RecyclerView`. When I init my view everything is ok and fine. But when I update my RecyclerView  (parent) my view is automatic scroll to first child RecyclerView I do not see an item in parent RecyclerView (is only a `TextView`). I do not know why it happend. When I create a view for first time all is ok.

**Layout of main view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.EventsListActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/top_panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
            android:background="@drawable/top_menu_blue">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/event_categories_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top_panel"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my itemVIew :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20sp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_category_name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_events"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_category_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**This is how I put and update a main view:**

```
private fun initEventsRecyclerView(
    context: Context,
    interaction: EventAdapter.Interaction
) {
    event_categories_list.run {
        eventCategoryAdapter = EventCategoryAdapter(
            eventsListModel.eventList,
            eventsListModel.ticketsList,
            interaction,
            context
        )

        adapter = eventCategoryAdapter

        isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
        setHasFixedSize(true)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    }
}
```

**And this is how I put on item :**

```
itemView.list_events.apply {
    if (eventCategory.eventsList != null) {
        val eventCategoryAdapter = EventAdapter(
            eventCategory,
            eventCategory.eventsList,
            ticketList,
            interaction,
            context
        )
        adapter = eventCategoryAdapter
    }

    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
    setHasFixedSize(true)
}
```

// edit 
When I do this for updateView :

```
eventCategoryAdapter.updateEventsCategoryList(eventsListModel.getFilterEvents(dt.time))
        eventCategoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

steal is scrolled view down

// edit

**This is a main adapter :**

```
class EventCategoryAdapter(
    eventsCategoryList: List<EventCategory>,
    ticketList: ArrayList<Ticket>,
    private val interaction: EventAdapter.Interaction? = null,
    val context: Context
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<EventCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var eventsCategory = mutableListOf<EventCategory>()
    private val ticketListForEvents = ArrayList<Ticket>()

    init {
        eventsCategory.addAll(eventsCategoryList)
        ticketListForEvents.addAll(ticketList)
    }

    fun updateEventsCategoryList(eventsCategoryList: List<EventCategory>){
        eventsCategory = eventsCategoryList as MutableList<EventCategory>
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_category_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(
            view
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = eventsCategory.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(eventsCategory[position],ticketListForEvents, context, interaction)
    }


    class ViewHolder(
        itemView: View
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bind(
            eventCategory: EventCategory,
            ticketList :ArrayList<Ticket>,
            context: Context,
            interaction: EventAdapter.Interaction?
        ) {
            itemView.tv_category_name.text = eventCategory.name
            itemView.list_events

            itemView.list_events.apply {
                if (eventCategory.eventsList != null) {
                    val eventCategoryAdapter = EventAdapter(
                        eventCategory,
                        eventCategory.eventsList,
                        ticketList,
                        interaction,
                        context
                    )
                    adapter = eventCategoryAdapter
                }

            }
            val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
            itemView.list_events.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
            itemView.list_events.isNestedScrollingEnabled = true
            itemView.list_events.setHasFixedSize(true)
            itemView.list_events.layoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        }
    }

}
```

**and this is child adapter :**

```
class EventAdapter(
    private val eventCategory: EventCategory,
    eventsList: List<Event?>,
    ticketList: ArrayList<Ticket>,
    private val interaction: Interaction? = null,
    val context: Context
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private val events = mutableListOf<Event?>()
    private val ticketListForEvents = ArrayList<Ticket>()

    init {
        events.addAll(eventsList)
        ticketListForEvents.addAll(ticketList)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(
            view,
            interaction
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = events.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val event = events[position]
        if (event?.id != null)
            holder.bind(
                event,
                eventCategory,
                getTicketsForEvent(event.id, ticketListForEvents),
                context
            )
    }


    class ViewHolder(
        itemView: View,
        private val interaction: Interaction?
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bind(
            event: Event,
            eventCategory: EventCategory,
            ticketList: ArrayList<Ticket>?,
            context: Context
        ) {
            val activity = context as AppCompatActivity

            itemView.iv_event_thumbnail.clipToOutline = true

            Glide.with(context)
                .load("${BASE_URL}xxx${event.thumbnail}")
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .override(500,500)
                .into(itemView.iv_event_thumbnail)
            if (ticketList != null && ticketList.size > 0) {
                itemView.ticket_info_panel.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                itemView.iv_ticket_end.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                itemView.tv_ticket_counter.text = ticketList.size.toString()
            } else {
                itemView.ticket_info_panel.visibility = View.GONE
                itemView.iv_ticket_end.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            itemView.tv_event_name.text = event.title
            itemView.tv_event_short_descr.text = event.shortDescription
            itemView.setOnClickListener {
                interaction?.onItemSelected(adapterPosition, event, eventCategory,ticketList)
            }
        }
    }

    interface Interaction {
        fun onItemSelected(
            position: Int,
            event: Event,
            eventCategory: EventCategory,
            ticketList: ArrayList<Ticket>?
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach in this case is to use RecyclerView with multiple view type (multiple view holder).

You can create multiple classes inheriting same class (or implementing same interface. For this example I will create 2 of them ("name" and "photo"):

```
class NameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView name;

    NameViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
    }
}
```

and

```
class PhotoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView image;

    PhotoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_avatar);
    }
}
```

You have to prepare numbers (positions) to those items, e.g.:

```
private static int TYPE_NAME = 1;
private static int TYPE_PHOTO = 2;
```

And in your adapter, base on some logic return which type do you need.
Here you are returning "for which position from list, which view holder"

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // Add here your logic!
    if (people.get(position).hasPhoto()) {
        return TYPE_PHOTO;
    } else {
        return TYPE_NAME;
    }
}
```

Next inside `onCreateViewHolder()` (in your adapter) you have to inflate proper layout:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View view;
    if (viewType == TYPE_PHOTO) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_photo, viewGroup, false);
        return new PhotoViewHolder(view);

    } else { // for email layout
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_name, viewGroup, false);
        return new NameViewHolder(view);
    }
}
```

And fill them properly (in `onBindViewHolder()`):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Person person = people.get(position);

    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_PHOTO) {
        ((PhotoViewHolder) viewHolder).bind(person);
    } else {
        ((NameViewHolder) viewHolder).bind(person);
    }
}
```